# AJAX call to async method is success, but data returned is undefined

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, asynchronous

I have a controller, and when I Debug.WriteLine the data which I'm returning it's exactly like it's supposed to be. I'm very new to async in .NET, but it seems something gets lost between the controller and the view, because the AJAX call is a success, but the data which I'm returning is undefined when I try to work with it.

Below is the method in the controller. Here the data is correct, and as far as I know this method works exactly as it should.

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> getServerProcesses(string server)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        QueryPair<JToken, JToken> processes = new QueryPair<JToken, JToken>();

        using (client)
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var processesRequest = ProcessURLAsync(baseUrl + "activityMonitor/" + server + "/processes", client);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await processesRequest;
            var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
            var data = json.SelectToken("Processes" + ".Data");
            var columns = json.SelectToken("Processes" + ".Columns");
            processes.Data = data;
            processes.Columns = columns;

            Debug.WriteLine(data);
        }

        return Json(processes);
    }
```

As you can see I use an alert to confirm the success, but when I try something such as getting the length it says it's undefined. Even when I just try to console.log the object it says it's undefined.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/getServerProcesses',
        data: {'server': server},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Length: " + data.length);
            alert("oui");
            $('#server-name').empty();
            $('#server-name').append(server);
            var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            for (var i = 0; i < pmdfields.length; i++) dataTable.addColumn('string', pmdfields[i]);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) dataTable.addRow(data[i]);
            var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('processTable'));
            table.draw(dataTable, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert('ajax getServerProcesses POST request error');
        }
    });
```

From API. Under response it has an empty JSON object full of empty arrays. I suspect the error is in my controller class:[image: Network tab]

[image: Preview]

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(data)`?

Comment: It just says "undefined"

Comment: It means data returning from api is not present. Check the network tab and see if you can find the response in the api there and paste the snapshot of response here

Comment: Please paste the preview option right to Headers

Comment: Sorry, I added it. It's empty (as expected), but I don't understand why. The Debug.WriteLine in the controller shows the data correctly, but somehow it's empty when it's returned.